# How to handle IE popup in selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I am writing tests for a web App using selenium WebDriver and came across a scenario where when I try to close the browser I get a popup saying "Are you sure? The page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data entered will be lost." with 2 buttons: Leave Page and Stay on Page

How do I click on those buttons? I tried this [Selenium WebDriver how to close browser popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup)
But it ends up by saying No alert is active. But actually I can see the pop up.

```
Utils.pressEnterKey(driver,driver.findElement(By.xpath(testSystem.getXPath("SearchBox")))); 
Utils.waitForPageToLoad(driver);
String browser=TestSystem.getInstance().getBrowser();
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
{System.out.println("IE handling");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

Only for IE this popup issue. So a check provided.

Comment: Can you share your selenium code? I think you are calling alert function before alert comes.

Comment: Utils.pressEnterKey(driver,driver.findElement(By.xpath(testSystem.getXPath("SearchBox")))); 
Utils.waitForPageToLoad(driver);
String browser=TestSystem.getInstance().getBrowser();

if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
{
Utils.waitForPageToLoad(driver);
System.out.println("IE handling");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}

Comment: share code with question please. in comment it is difficult to read.