# Method to close all browser windows, regardless of Alerts Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I am looking to see if anyone has a simple method I can use, to close all browser windows, regardless if there is an alert popup. Since, when I call `driver.quit()` it will not close the browser if an alert is present.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver how to close browser popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar situation before and use something like the following at the moment. Not a great solution but helps me to what I need to do. And, I also know why you would want something like this. It just does not kill the browsers also kills any `WebDriver` windows as well

**Please Note:** This is written in C#. Should not be too hard to convert

```
private static void KillBrowserProcesses()
{
    IEnumerable<Process> processes =
        Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(
                p =>
                    p.ProcessName == "chrome" || p.ProcessName == "iexplore" || p.ProcessName == "firefox" ||
                    p.ProcessName == "chromedriver" || p.ProcessName == "IEDriverServer")
            .ToList();
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```