# How to handle the Leave/Stay browser dialog in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, dialog, popup

[image]

I am not able to handle this browser dialog in my selenium c# code. The switchTo().alert doesn't work for this dialog. Is there any way we can handle such dialogs?

Comment: Just try using `WebDriverWait` to handle this alert as [`new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent()).Accept();`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_AlertIsPresent.htm)

Comment: Its not working. The webdriver gives timeout exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup)

or

You can try [keyboard event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) as well

```
public event KeyPressEventHandler KeyPress
```