# How to click confirm navigation box with protractor

Tags: protractor

I am running multiple cases using --suites config in protractor. I have to launch my webapp newly for each case but my app is having an alert which will be pop out for the confirmation [Stay on this page or Leave the page] whenever the page reloads or closed. In that case protractor throws an error

> WARN - Exception: unexpected alert open:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Switch to](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo) the alert and *accept* it:

```
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

---

This though might not work in Chrome, in this case [you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7034926/771848):

```
browser.executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function(e){};");
```

Answer (score 1):

No of the found solutions had worked for me until I found a snippet in a Protractor thread.
This:

```
browser.get(url).catch(function () {
    return browser.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {
        alert.accept();
        return browser.get(url);
    });
});
```

I hope this solution works for someone who, like me, was already desperate :P