# Turn off 'non-secure form' warning in Safari using selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium, safari, warnings

In my selenium auto tests I need to close warning popup in Safari browser.
Is it possible to turn-off ['non-secure form' popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBQ2e.png)? Maybe it is possible to click 'Send' using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Turn the warning off (client side)

> Safari-Preferences-Security - "Ask before sending a non-secure form from a secure website"

But this isn't safe. Is your webpage secured with `HTTPS`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, it is HTTPS and I can't turn off it manually, because it runs on a remote server, so I'm looking for some code to turn-off the popup in selenium tests

Answer (score 0):

i hope alert accept will works. dismiss for cancel.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();  //in java
```

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately safari webdriver doesn't work with alerts at all