# WebDriver switchTo().alert() function fails

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getelementbyid

Have this line in my html:

```
<a class="btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post?')" href="#">
```

Try to switch to the pop-up window and click OK by using

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

but it keeps giving me AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'. I also try to locate the element ID of the buttons of the pop-up window but I could not make it work. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Python` you should use

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

as `switchTo()` is `Java` method

Comment: Thanks for your help! The code went through, however it's not confirming the action (not deleting the post in my case). Any idea why?

Comment: Update: Your code works perfectly fine in FireFox, I was testing it on Chrome earlier and it didn't work. This is really weird. Anyway, thanks a lot for help out. Still needs to figure out why it isn't working on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I am little late to answer, It is java syntax dear and you use python,

use this code:

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
    alert.accept()
```