# Ignore popup when close safari driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I use safari driver in my tests automation. When I try to use `driver.close()` to close safari, there is always a popup "Are you sure you want to quit this site"?

How can I ignore the popup or disable the popup? I want the browser to close directly when I do `driver.close`.

I use selenium 3.4 and safari 11.0, and Java.

Here's my code:

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseCleanSession(true);
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver(option);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Did you try `Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   alert.accept();`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver how to close browser popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup)

Answer (score 1):

While automating through *Selenium* as per the best practices you should invoke the `quit()` method within the `tearDown() {}`. Invoking `quit()` *DELETEs* the current browsing session through sending `"quit"` command with `{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}` and finally sends the `GET reques`t on `/shutdown EndPoint`.

So instead of :

```
driver.close();
```

Use :

```
driver.quit();
```

You will find a detailed discussion in Selenium : [How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

Comment: It's still going to prompt in the same way so this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give a chance to the OP to try out the option and report back the status before downvoting?