# can't interact with popup chrome extention using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I'm writing a script to automate a task on chrome,I'm using Python and Selenium,the problem is that the task requires clicking on a button in a chrome extension popup to finish the task but I can't initiate the click() class on a chrome extension popup using selenium.

Do you have any idea on how we can solve such a problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium WebDriver how to close browser popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, since no one answered my question I will answer how I solved this issue all I did was use the Pynput library to interact with the Chrome extension by simulating keyboard clicks.

To toggle between pages and elements I had to use the Tab button which converts to the following Python code:

```py
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press(Key,tab)
keyboard.release(Key,tab)
```

I also added some delay between each activity so it runs smoothly. This might not be the best solution but at least it works now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).