# How to close a browser alert with webdriver

Tags: javascript, browser, webdriver-io

A web driver test produces a browser alert: `Do you want to leave this page? Cancel | Continue.`  None of the following commands selects the `Continue` button.

```
await browser.acceptAlert()
await browser.pressKeyCode(13) // 13 = Enter key
await browser.confirm()
```

These have been tried in the content of the `afterEach` :

```
describe('xxx', () => {
    afterEach(async () => {
        await browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');
        await browser.deleteAllCookies()
        await browser.execute('sessionStorage.clear()')
        await browser.refresh()
        // await browser.acceptAlert() // not working
        // await browser.pressKeyCode(13) // not working
        // await browser.confirm() // not working
        await browser.pause(1000)
    });
```

Using web driver v7.

This is the alert:

[image]

Is this an OS alert rather than a native browser alert?

**Edit**

In `wdio.conf.js` I now have:

```
capabilities: [
    {
        maxInstances: 6,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-prompt-on-repost']
        },
```

(based on https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile/) but VS Code says:

```
ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file:
/Users/User/Documents/Projects/wdio-visual-regression-testing/wdio.conf.js:
chromeOptions is not defined
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7034926/667903) is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution #1: addEventListener

Try using

```
window.addEventListner("beforeunload", (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

## Solution #2: pressKeyCode

The pressKeyCode function takes two arguments. You can use one for the keyCode, but, you can only use **strings**. If that doesn't work try pressing the tab key with

```
browser.setValue('input', ['Tab'])
```

and then, don't forget to press the enter key

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I try `await browser.pause(2000); await browser.setValue('input', ['Tab']); await browser.acceptAlert()` I get `browser.setValue is not a function`. Can you explain your `addEventListener` solution? Will this interfere with anything else? When I try that in the `beforeEach`, I get `window is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

### Try browser.keys()

I think they removed support for browser.setValue in v5, so instead you can try using `browser.keys("\uE007")` instead. the \uE007 means the enter key.

### Explanation of the addEventListener

For the addEventListener, it adds a listener for when the page unloads and stops all the other beforeunload event listeners using stopImmediatePropagation(). You can read more about stopImmediatePropagation() here: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Comment: Unfortunately `browser.keys("\uE007")` did not work. Using `"@wdio/cli": "^7.19.6",`